Issue appears during PXE booting on Ubuntu, Unable to find a medium containing a live file system ubuntu
I have a PXE boot server on Ubuntu. It should serve Debian ISO and Ubuntu as well. Debian iso loads to a  new machine properly, but the problem occurs when I choose Ubuntu. vmlinuz and initrd are being loaded well, but at the end I get Unable to find a medium containing a live file system ubuntu .
It's configuration of file ,,default'' which is located at /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
UI menu.c32
MENU TITLE PXE Boot Menu

LABEL Debian Net Boot
    MENU LABEL Debian
    KERNEL debian/install.amd/vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=debian/install.amd/initrd.gz

LABEL Ubuntu Server Minimal
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu
    KERNEL ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
    APPEND vga=788 initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd

The directory structure looks like this.
kuba@kuba-Virtual-Machine:/tftpboot$ ls
debian  ldlinux.e64  libutil.c32  menu.c32  pxelinux.cfg  syslinux.efi  ubuntu
kuba@kuba-Virtual-Machine:/tftpboot$ cd ubuntu/
kuba@kuba-Virtual-Machine:/tftpboot/ubuntu$ ls
boot  boot.catalog  casper  dists  EFI  install  md5sum.txt  pool
kuba@kuba-Virtual-Machine:/tftpboot/ubuntu$ cd casper/
kuba@kuba-Virtual-Machine:/tftpboot/ubuntu/casper$ ls
filesystem.manifest
filesystem.size
initrd
install-sources.yaml
ubuntu-server-minimal.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs.gpg
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs.gpg
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs.gpg
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs.gpg
vmlinuz

DHCP and tftp work as they should. DHCP points to option bootfile-name "syslinux.efi";
Do you have any ideas what is missing?

